# ReportItems when using two tables on a single report

Tags: reporting-services

I have two tablix tables on a report, which are using the same dataset. I'm trying to display some data from the table in a separate textbox area above the table.  The data in the tables shows fine, but the textbox values are blank.

Is there something special regarding the "scope" of reportitems regarding the values that would be displayed in the textboxes?

The layout is something like this

```
textbox1 = ReportItems!MerchantCode.Value

Table A <br/>
MerchantCode

< page break >

textbox1 = ReportItems!MerchantCode1.Value

Table B <br/>
MerchantCode1
```

[ **update** ]
What I did to resolve this, was replace the "extra" textboxes ABOVE the table(s), with extra row WITHIN the table, then using expressions that reference fields of the dataset, rather than textbox values.  Still wondering however, why the the values with the table will display but referencing that textbox from OUTSIDE the table results in an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use dataset name in the expression.

e.g.:

```
=First(Fields!MerchantCode.Value, "Dataset1")
```

Comment: While that will work in some cases, I dont need the first value of the dataset.  Im still curious why using the ReportItems collection results in an empty value, whereas when I had but one tablix on the report, data would show up in the extra texboxes using ReportItems.   So my question still stands, why would the textbox display a value while in the table, but referenced from outside the table, the value is blank.